# Appending multiple instances of the same report together?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a report that basically is being used to populate textboxes using an sql query for a given order number. This generates the invoice well but i am now trying to see if its possible to rerun the same report with another order number through the sql query but append the new report onto the first one to basically have two concatenated instances of the report for export as a pdf. I've looked and the only thing ive found is using something like:

```
Dim reportinstance As New Report_Invoice
```

but i'm lost on how to repopulate the new instance with different data and append it together, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how you are building your report, but there should be some mechanism to have a page group breaking option on some condition... such as page break on invoiceid.  From that, have your query gets all the data for the invoices, but its order-by clause would have all of one order together before the next and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WHERE part of the report's parameters to do this. Something like:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptInvoice",acViewPreview,,"InvoiceID IN(1,4)"
```

This will open the report `rptInvoice` limited to show those that have an `InvoiceID` of either 1 or 4. You may need to build up the `WHERE` statement using VBA, perhaps from choices selected in a list box.